# Transaction Issue with Multiple Tests in TestsNG

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, testng

I am having two test cases, where first test case saves the record and second updates the record which is added in first test case. I am using JPA/Hibernate as ORM.

My TestNG test class is like below:

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:application-context-test.xml")
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
public class MyEntityTest {

    int long myEntityId; 

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public saveTest(){
      session=getCurrentSessionFactory()
      myEntity = new myEntity();
      myEntityId = session.save(myEntity)
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods={"saveTest"})
    @Transactional
    public updateTest(){
      session=getCurrentSession()
      myEntity =session.getByID(myEntityId)
      session.update(myEntity)
    }
}
```

But when the second test case is executed then this prompts the error that record/entity does not exist.

Even both tests are annotated as **@Transactional**, still seems tests are executed in separate transaction.

Any Idea? Am I missing anything important? Is this a proper way to execute the tests or should I follow some different approach?

Comment: By default spring rollsback the transaction after the execution of a test method. In general it is a bad idea to have test methods depend on each other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What should be the way to test update method based on data which is in session kept during save test execution?

Comment: In either way, how we can keep two TestNG tests in single transaction?

Comment: As mentioned it is a bad idea to do that. But if you really must, add the `@Rollback` annotation to the `saveTest` method and set it to `false`. Beware that you don't have a single transaction but 2 transactions! You will NOT be able to rollback the previous transaction!.

Comment: I agree with you that it can be the bad idea. But in case my DAO layer is having CRUD operations and I want to perform test for all database operations like Save, Update, Delete etc.. What should be the proper way? Any how I have to execute my save first and have to perform update and delete on saved record without unnecessary populating database with test data.What would you say?

Comment: Populate your database before you execute the method with something like DbUnit (and search for spring integration). That way you can consistently run your tests, you know what data is in there and you don't have the risk of other tests polluting your database. Now you have 2 simple tests, we have a project with over 5000 tests, maintained by 6 teams of 6 developers, you don't want failed tests because someone forgot to cleanup the database or suddenly commits something which breaks 2000 other tests!.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43028/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-m-deinum)